# Capturing the last line

Tags: perl, powershell, pipeline

I need to process a file that contains some lines beginning with a dash (-); these are continuation lines that need to be appended to the previous line.  so what I have is something like:

```
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
  - adipiscing elit. Donec 
  - consectetur lotis. 
  Sed a est dui.
  Curabitur placerat a tortor
  - vel sodales.
```

and what I want is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur - adipiscing elit. Donec - consectetur lotis.
Sed a est dui. 
Curabitur placerat a tortor - vel sodales.
```

so I've written something like this:

```
$s = ""
cat $f |%{
    if ($_ -match "^-") { $s += $_ } else { $s; $s = $_; }
} |out-file x.txt
```

My question is: in cases when the file ends with dashed lines, the script never outputs the final line, because upon receipt of the final line from the pipe, it doesn't know it's the final line.

In Perl I used to be able to use a construct like END {} to do these things.  How would that be handled in Powershell?

**Update**

Perl is relevant because in that language I could do something like (where `txt` is a file containing the relevant text):

```
perl -lne '
   BEGIN { $s = "" };
   if (/^-/) { $s .= $_ } else { print $s; $s = $_; }
   END { print $s; }
   ' txt
```

where, as you can see, the END{} construct solves my problem

Comment: What does this have to do with perl?

Comment: Thank you for trying. Show your Perl code so that we can fix it

Comment: @Flimzy: What do you mean?

Comment: @Borodin: The question is about doing something in powershell. I don't see how perl relates...

Comment: @Flimzy: SO is broken so that you can remove your contribution to a thread, but it makes nonsense of what is left so please don't. The OP needs to clarify his requirements.

Comment: @Borodin: I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: I'm voting to close because the question is unclear

Comment: It seems clear enough to me... he's asking how to accomplish something in powershell, which he has done in perl before. I still think the `perl` tag is misplaced.

Comment: @Borodin, the question, simplified is: how do I accomplish in Powershell what I can accomplish in Perl as X, where X is the END {} construct

Comment: @Borodin, Perl is relevant to this post because it offers the capability I'm asking for in Powershell

Comment: I agree with `@Flimzy` and believe that your comment should be added to the post and the `Perl` tag should be removed.

Comment: @Borodin, I don't think I get you. the perl tag is there because this is a question that concerns two technologies, not one.

Comment: Tags are primarily a search device. People will look at this question either because they have Perl expertise or because they have a Perl problem. I am looking at your post because I am very capable with Perl. But that is irrelevant to your problem so I feel cheated and mislead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version, using your code:

```
$s = ""
cat $f | % {
    if ($_ -match "^-") { $s += $_ } else { $s; $s = $_; }
} -end { $s } | out-file x.txt
```

longer version:

```
function glue {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param(
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
      $line
   )
   begin { $output = "" }
   process { if ($line -match "^-") { $output += $line } else { $output; $output = $line; }
   end { $output }
}
cat $f | glue | out-file x.txt
```

Comment: that's it mate!  awesome.  it's even called the same as in Perl !

Comment: for anyone wondering what the advantage of the function approach above is... it's performance.  about 100% faster than the loop

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear whether the leading spaces are preswent in your data source.

If your file is smaller than a few megabytes, then it is most simple to read all of the data into memory and remove the newlines.

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do {
  local $/;
  <DATA>;
};

$data =~ s/\s*\n\s+-/ -/g;

print $data;

__DATA__
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
  - adipiscing elit. Donec 
  - consectetur lotis. 
  Sed a est dui.
  Curabitur placerat a tortor vel sodales.
```

**output**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur - adipiscing elit. Donec - consectetur lotis. 
  Sed a est dui.
  Curabitur placerat a tortor vel sodales.
```